# How to replace a CFL recessed light with LED fixture

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

I bought a few LED new light fixtures and was able to replace them in bedroom in 5-10 minutes each. But the ones in kitchen had a weird CFL format and not the usual lightbulb screw kind of holder so not sure what are my options.

I am attaching pictures of the current fixture and the new LED fixture that I bought. Any ideas appreciated.

Should I just snip the current holder and the new light bulb adapter and splice the black wire with the red and the white with the blue? Is that it?

[image: what the fixture looked like before]
[image]
[image: busted lamp]
[image: new GE LED fixture and lamp]

Comment: you're going to have to remove that "can" and disconnect the ballast  and connect the new fittng to the power wires , this may require a different type of led fitting, I can't see how the one you've got can be compliant here, but my NEC knowledge is weak. and I haven't seen behind that can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The blue and red wires you see in the existing fixture come from the ballast for the CFL bulb. It's not  the regular 120V. You'll need to remove the old fixture to get to the 120 Volts you need and install a new fixture.

Comment: Thanks @JACK. That makes sense - I never considered earlier that a ballast would be required. I have never quite changed a fixture so will have to consider the amount of work required. I assume that attic access might be required which is quite cramped.

Comment: @Guraaf  check the inside of your fixture for screws, brackets, clamps, etc.,  Sometimes you can undo the fixture from below and remove it without attic access.

Comment: Thanks again. I found a few YouTube videos and found it was straightforward enough. However, the canister is clipped and not screwed. I just couldn't get the clip to budge. There are 4 of them. 

The can itself is Halo H572RICAT. I found the instruction manual for installation but that didn't give me any clue on how to remove them. There is a smallish notch on it but too small to even hold with a nose plier and pull down.

Comment: @Guraaf  You should be able to push the bracket up and then pull it out and down...

Comment: Thanks @JACK. I couldn't figure this out. What didn't make sense to me is how is the canister held in place? If I push it up then how will I eventually bring it down and put it back in place after removing the ballast? I will continue to look online for a potential instructive video.

Comment: @Guraaf There should be  mall slot in the can and when you move th bracket to that slot, the bracket can be pulled out releasing the tension it has to the ceiling.  Keep trying... when you do get it, you'll wonder wht it took so long.. lol

Comment: Thanks much. I will try. What is a "mall slot"? Do I push the bracket up or down to release the bracket or do I rotate the bracket in the current ceiling hole? Just some idea as to what am I doing? Thanks much.

Comment: Small slot.. sorry about that..Should move it down to the slot than pull out, down..... that's the ones I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily bypass the ballast, connect your hot to red neutral to white and use color tape to designate for future.  The sockets can be adapted with plug in to medium adapter.  Faster and easier then replacing the can.
I do this literally all the time

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to remove the canister to get to the black/white wires above but am unable to remove the can from below as it is clipped. Not screwed. The can is Halo H572RICAT and I couldn't figure out how to remove the clip

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the fixture with a remodle can light. Then your led trim can go into that